# Jasmine unit test where service call observable behaves differently than property

Tags: angular, rxjs, karma-jasmine

I am trying to write some tests for a component. One scenario where I directly invoke the mocked service succeeds and another scenario where a property is the functions invocation. Trying to understand what the difference is and why one scenario works and the other doesn't.

My spy

```
spyOn(searchDataService, 'getQuickFindOptions').and.returnValue(of(searchOptions));
```

My observable and constructor

```
constructor(public searchDataService: SearchDataService) { }
public test$ = this.searchDataService.getQuickFindOptions();
```

This test completes and passes

```
it('should get search options from the search service', done => {
      component.searchDataService.getQuickFindOptions().subscribe(response=> {
        debugger;
        expect(response).toBe(searchOptions);
        done();
      });
  });
```

This test never completes and I get the following error.
**Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL)**

```
it('should get search options from the search service', done => {
      component.test$.subscribe(response=> {
        debugger;
        expect(response).toBe(searchOptions);
        done();
      });
  });
```

Comment: Can you take a look at https://medium.com/@shashankvivek.7/testing-a-component-with-stub-services-and-spies-in-jasmine-1428d4242a49 and see if this helps ?  I think `spyOn` is not being applied at correct lifecycle. Please provide component `ts` and `spec` code. Also, there should be a better way to test than using `subscribe()` inside `it` block. With your component code added, I can suggest something. But please 1st refer to the article as well

Comment: might you share how to setup TestBed and when the spy is defined?